# crypto.subtle don't exist even with webcrypto-shim

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, cryptography, jwt

I'm making a Cordova app with backbone and my goal was to achieve socket authentification with a JSON Web Token (JWT).

To sign my JWT, I used [webcrypto-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webcrypto-jwt) and it worked well when using the app in the browser.

Then I tried the app on my mobile and BBAAMM...
[webcrypto-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webcrypto-jwt) uses the browser's `window.crypto.subtle` module.

```
var cryptoSubtle = (window.crypto && crypto.subtle) ||
(window.crypto && crypto.webkitSubtle) ||
  (window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.Subtle);
```

But no subtle on android web view!

So I used [webcrypto-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webcrypto-shim) to add the crypto.subtle. But it doesn't work.

That's a screenshot of my cordova's `window` object. It does have a crypto key but with no subtle in it!

[image: screen of window object]

So I can't sign my JWT.

Comment: Don't put the tags in the title unless it's really necessary (e.g. _How to combine tech X with Y?_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research and tests I have found a pure js library that works on cordova.

[jsrsasign](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/)

I used it to authentificate my JWT. It doesn't use the the crypto.subtle module.

```
        // Header
        var oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' };
        // Payload
        var oPayload = {};
        var tNow = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now');
        var tEnd = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now + 1day');
        oPayload.iss = "http://foobar.com";
        oPayload.sub = "mailto:someone@hello.com";
        oPayload.iat = tNow;
        oPayload.exp = tEnd;
        oPayload.jti = "id123";
        oPayload.aud = "http://someUrl";
        oPayload.email = "userEmail";
        oPayload.pwd = "userPassword";
        oPayload.deviceId = "deviceId";

        // Sign JWT.
        var sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
        var sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
        //secret -> your secret that the server gave you.
        var sJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("HS256", sHeader, sPayload, secret);
        console.log(sJWT);
```

So that's it. It solved my problem.
I know that the undefined crypto.subtle error still exists. I did not find any solutions to that problem.
I supose that one day the developers in charge of cordova will make the effort to support the cryto module that we can find in all other browser but for now the only solution is to used third party libraries.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner will provide you a working webcrypto on most platforms.

I have used it with https://github.com/square/js-jose just fine.

You can test your browsers support for WebCrypto with this - https://peculiarventures.github.io/pv-webcrypto-tests/

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

WebCryptographyApi is not supported on Android WebView, and webcrypto-shim is not targeted to this component

> The library is targeted to fix these browsers having prefixed and buggy webcrypto api implementations:
>
> Internet Explorer 11, Mobile Internet Explorer 11,
> Safari 8+, iOS Safari 8+.

So you are getting the expected behaviour. I think `window.crypto` that is showing Cordova is the old implementation.

If you need key storage  I suggest use the Android native keystore (or iOS if you build for it). If you are looking for cryptographic function, include a pure javascript library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll search for jwt signing in pure JS then.